# Reddit API /api/morechildren returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" using mootools

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, mootools, reddit

I've tried the following basic Reddit API morechildren request using mootools:

```
var moreChildren = new Request({
  async: true,
  url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/morechildren',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    api_type: "json",
    children: "cl2vjlp",
    link_id:  "2ijczu",
    sort:     "top"
  },
  onSuccess: function(response){
    commentData = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(commentData);
  }
});

// tried above request with and without the following line
delete moreChildren.headers["X-Requested-With"]; 

moreChildren.send();
```

And I'm receiving a `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reddit.com/api/morechildren.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.` in Google Chrome.

Observations:

- Adding .json to reddit/api/morechildren(.json) does not resolve
- deleting "X-Requested-With" header does not resolve

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of same origin policy - CORS.

you do well to remove this:

```
// tried above request with and without the following line
delete moreChildren.headers["X-Requested-With"];
```

but if the reddit site does not support it, it won't work.

you have 2 options:

- local proxy, ajax call to local, local server-side to reddit, back and output to browser
- use JSONP where available.

can't test your case as it needs oauth but via info.json which is GET, you can:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/zy3rwpjs/

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json',
    callbackKey: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        url: 'http://www.reddit.com/buttons'
    },
    onSuccess: function(response){
        console.log(response.data, response.kind);    
      }
}).send();
```

obviously, when it expects POST, things get more complex... JSONP works as GET.

if all you care about is your own project and google chrome, you can start with with `--disable-web-security` flag, which will allow the call.